# Terms rewriting system for solving systems of algebraic equations

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

## Problem description

Having system of equations as input (in whatever format):

```
x + y = 6
2x + y = 9
```

I would like to output manual, step-by-step high-school-like solution. In other words applying rules from a ruleset one at a time:

```
Step 1: 
x = 6 - y
2x + y = 9
Step 2:
x = 6 - y
2 * (6 - y) + y = 9
Step 3:
x = 6 - y
12 - 2y + y = 9
Step 4:
x = 6 - y
-2y + y = 9 - 12
Step 5:
x = 6 - y
-y = 9 - 12
Step 6:
x = 6 - y
-y = -3
Step 7:
x = 6 - y
y = 3
Step 8:
x = 6 - 3
y = 3
Step 9:
x = 3
y = 3
```

Let's assume that system is always solvable. I'm trying to write this program in **Node**, but underlying technology is a secondary issue.

## Question

**Is there some terms rewriting system / expert system which can do this?**
Or is this problem more complex then I think and there is no simple, automated solution?

Comment: Only simple linear equations like the one in this example? Or different types?

Comment: Only simple equations like above + parenthesis and integer powers. The most complicated ones should look like this:
(x - 2)^2 + x^4 = 17 + y

Comment: For linear equations - like the one in your question - one could use the standard [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). For polynomial equations, however, like the one in your comment, there may not even be a solution, or it may only be possible to find a symbolic, closed solution, only a numerical one. I would recommend to google for "polynomial equation solver". What you are asking for might be  part of some computer algebra systems, check [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems)

Answer (score 0):

The software that can do that and more is [MathXpert](https://www.helpwithmath.com/index.php). It used to be a paid software but now is released for free. It can solve math problems step by step.